# How to use sprinklr stream feed API

Tags: php, laravel, sprinklr

I have key and secret from a sprinkler.
I have stream Id.
I have auth_token too!

How do I call the following API?
https://developers.sprinklr.com/docs/read/core_platform_api/stream/Stream_Feed

It says use `GET` request, then I am confused where do I put my secret and key and `auth_token`.

I am trying this on `POSTMAN` ... please help me to call this `API`.

Comment: @Nikunj Patel have you any idea about it

Answer (score 0):

You must put your token and key on request header like followings. And you don't need your Secret code anymore after you got a token.

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer tokentokentoken
key:keykeykey
```

Thanks,